# facebook login facebooksdk showing error in android app

Tags: android

I am new in android programming. I am trying to login to facebook in android app.
When adding facebooksdk.jar as external jar, it is showing as error in project-->properties-->android. How to solve this error?

Comment: please share the errors too and try to use facebook sdk as a library project

Comment: error showing a cross sign in project-->properties-->android. section. It is already given as library project

Comment: might be it is not added as a library project, try to remove that and add again

Comment: [2014-11-22 12:29:28 - Demo] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,

Comment: I tried this. And now that error has gone but the above error is showing. I removed this android-support-v4.jar and again added as external jar. Then also error is showing

Comment: copy android-support-v4.jar from facebook sdk libs folder to your project libs folder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your project and library are in same work space